# Outlook - Windows Phishing Report Button

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I am looking to get confirmation on whether this is possible.

My issue with the report phishing button is it removes the email once reported and gets put into the deleted items folder for users. Once it is reviewed by me the user then gets an email that yes the email is clean, spam, or phish email. The email, if it's clean I would like it to be automatically recovered to their inbox. Is this possible?

I might not have looked in the right spot for the admin portal for this, but currently have a P1 license, E3, on my test account and am unable to find a setting to recover email that was marked as clean automatically to the inbox.

Comment: Hi @KappaLeader3, you can use a graph call to move the item to the inbox after the message has been reviewed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-move?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript